# Regex for newline

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am trying to replace the `>` character newline, but unable to figure out the regex part.

I want:

```
"<StartTag>"
```

To be replaced with:

```
"<StartTag>\n"
```

but NOT:

```
"</EndTag>\n"
```

When I use `tags_string.Replace(">", "\n")`, it replaces both.

Can anyone please help with Regex, so I can use `Regex.Replace()` instead, to handle the EndTag case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following pattern to match the opening tag:

```
(<[^/][^>]*>)
```

Then replace it with `$1\n`.

```
Regex.Replace(yourText, @"(<[^/][^>]*>)", "$1\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider...

> string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\<\w*)>", @">\n");